# Sorting arrays in Scala: performance issues

Tags: scala, garbage-collection

```
val a = new Array[(Int, Int)](250000000)
... // initialization here

// #1
val b = a.sortBy(_._1)
// This part completely kills GC, 
// and I allocate plenty of heap memory (30GB)
// more than it's trying to use

// #2
val b = a.sorted
// Kills GC as efficiently as #1

// #3
val b = a.sortWith(_._1 < _._1)
// This part doesn't kill GC, but
// takes long to complete (224s)
// and still requires 10GB of heap

// #4
val a = new Array[Long](250000000)
java.util.Arrays.sort(a)
// Alternative version
// which takes only 2.7GB
// and completes in 40 secs
```

By killing GC I mean it's working like crazy using all 16 cores (I know I can reduce # of cores for GC, but it doesn't solve the problem)

Okay, I understand there is an overhead for #3 (objects, immutable operation), not sure it should take 5x amount of time and 4x amount of heap, but it's the price I guess. But I'm puzzled with #1 and #2. Should I avoid implicit ordering as a plague? What's happening there? I'm probably doing it wrong?

Scala version: 2.12.4

Comment: Are you sorting zeroed arrays ?

Comment: Nope, random integers.

Comment: Primitives are always going to be faster and use less memory than objects, in your fast example you are using primitive Long values instead of tuple objects, it would be more fair to use Long in all cases or use a tuple in all, but not sometimes one and sometimes the other.  The 4th example is also the only one that doesn't create a copy of the array (arrays.sort sorts in place instead of creating a sorted copy).

Comment: @puhlen I understand that primitives are faster and more compact (still 5x looks sad, Long = 8 bytes, (Int, Int) = 8 bytes without overhead). But the fact that #1 and #2 generate tons of garbage is disturbing (can easily hit 20GB mark as opposed to stable 10GB for #3).

Comment: @VictorMoroz `(Int, Int)` is 20 bytes *at least* and could very well be even more, objects in java have lots of overhead.  See how your test runs using a tuple instead of Long.  You also have to consider the impact of making a copy of such a large array.  Large arrays require not only lots of memory, but that memory must be contiguous which may require a GC cycle to compact the heap to make a big enough space.

Comment: @puhlen If I create custom `Comparator` it runs similar to #3. Didn't think about contiguous space (which is obvious in the hindsight), good advice, thanks. It can explain GC craziness (at least partially).

Answer (score 1):

Those methods requires it to create a copy of that array with the mapped values, then apply sorting with a custom comparator. `Arrays.sort` over integral values is much smarter - it can compare number directly and do not have to invoke any method to compare them.

Please find the implementation of those methods:

```
def sorted[B >: A](implicit ord: Ordering[B]): Repr = {
  val len = this.length
  val b = newBuilder
  if (len == 1) b ++= this
  else if (len > 1) {
    b.sizeHint(len)
    val arr = new Array[AnyRef](len)  // Previously used ArraySeq for more compact but slower code
    var i = 0
    for (x <- this) {
      arr(i) = x.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]
      i += 1
    }
    java.util.Arrays.sort(arr, ord.asInstanceOf[Ordering[Object]])
    i = 0
    while (i < arr.length) {
      b += arr(i).asInstanceOf[A]
      i += 1
    }
  }
  b.result()
}
```

---

I also think that when you have pairs of longs, you basically have memory footprint for a pair - i don't know if you also have a footprint for each long - consider using @specialized annotation to use real longs: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/specialized.html

Comment: `sortWith` is using `sorted` too, yet as I mentioned it's slower than `Arrays.sort` without comparator, but works. `sortBy` and `sorted` simply don't.

Comment: #1 requires applying a function to each element of array before comparing - for each comparison rather than once, #2 needs to compare whole pairs, so there are much more comparisons, #3 just does comparison

Comment: It's not just time, it's amount of garbage created on the way, which affects time and CPU load (creating an array of integers by `sortBy` doesn't explain it, it's much more than that). Just didn't expect it from library functions.